# Pass variable value to client side and store it in global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

Am still new to socket.io, Am trying to pass a value to the server side and store it in a global var which I can then use to do some logic with ARI.

So on my server side I have:

```
io.sockets.on('muting', function (data) {
    mute = data;
    console.log("client side:" + mute);
});
```

Entire server side code for clarity:

```
var ari = require('ari-client');
var util = require('util');
var chanArr = [];
var test;
var mute;
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//ARI client
ari.connect('http://localhost:8088', 'asterisk', 'asterisk', clientLoaded);

function clientLoaded(err, client) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    // find or create a holding bridges
    var bridge = null;
    client.bridges.list(function (err, bridges) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        bridge = bridges.filter(function (candidate) {
                return candidate.bridge_type === 'mixing';
            })[0];

        if (bridge) {
            console.log(util.format('Using bridge %s', bridge.id));
        } else {
            client.bridges.create({
                type : 'mixing'
            }, function (err, newBridge) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                bridge = newBridge;
                console.log(util.format('Created bridge %s', bridge.id));
            });
        }
    });

    // handler for StasisStart event
    function stasisStart(event, channel) {
        console.log(util.format(
                'Channel %s just entered our application, adding it to bridge %s',
                channel.name,
                bridge.id));

        channel.answer(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            bridge.addChannel({
                channel : channel.id
            }, function (err) {
                var id = chanArr.push(channel.name)
                    console.log("Value: " + test);
                test = channel.name;
                updateSip);

                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                //If else statement to start music for first user entering channel, music will stop once more than 1 enters the channel.
                if (chanArr.length <= 1) {
                    bridge.startMoh(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                } else if (chanArr.length === 2) {
                    bridge.stopMoh(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                } else {}

            });

        });

    }

    // handler for StasisEnd event
    function stasisEnd(event, channel) {
        console.log(util.format(
                'Channel %s just left our application', channel.name));
        console.log(channel.name);

        var index = chanArr.indexOf(channel.name);
        chanArr.splice(index, 1);
        updateSip();
    }
    client.on('StasisStart', stasisStart);
    client.on('StasisEnd', stasisEnd);
    client.start('bridge-hold');
}

//Socket.io logic here
server.listen(3009, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3009');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + "/testPage.html");
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (data) {
    updateSip();
});

io.sockets.on('muting', function (data) {
    mute = data;
    console.log("client side:" + mute);
});

function updateSip() {
    console.log("Value: " + test);
    io.sockets.emit('sip', chanArr);
}
```

And on my client side:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#kick', function() {
        mute = !mute;
        socket.emit('muting', mute);
        console.log(mute)
});
```

Full client side code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var socket = io.connect();
    var mute = false;
    var $sip = $('#sip');

    socket.on('sip', function (data) {
        var sip = '';
        $(".exe").remove();
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sip += data[i];
            if (sip) {
                $sip.append('<tr class="exe">\
                                                        <td>' + sip + '</td>\
                                                        <td><button class="btn btn-default mute" id="kick" type="submit">Mute</button></td>\
                                                        <td><button class="btn btn-default kick" id="kicks" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit">Kick</button></td>\
                                                        </tr>');
            } else {
                $sip.append('Currently no extensions');
            }
            sip = '';
        }

    });

    $('.kick').click(function () {
        $('#myInput').focus()
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#kick', function () {
        mute = !mute;
        socket.emit('muting', mute);
        console.log(mute)
    });

});
```

Am missing something very small, yet cant figure it out.

EDIT: I am not getting error messages, seems am not passing the information server side at all for some reason.

Am using express.

Kind regards.

Comment: Are you encountering an error?

Comment: @VC1 None, just been using the console.log to see if  the function runs. Seems like am not reaching it server side, otherwise it would get to console.log there which it doesn't. It only ever logs on the client side, leading me to understand am not passing it properly via socket.io. Not sure what am doing wrong.

Comment: You should provide more code from server side.

Comment: @Anonymous0day Provided the whole server side code, question now updated.

Comment: try a console.log after `io.sockets.on` before `updateSip();` to be sure that you reach your server

Comment: client-side i imagine that `socket` is the result of `io.connect` ??

Comment: @Anonymous0day am reaching the server fine, and yes it is `var socket = io.connect();` ill update the client side code now.

Comment: client-side be sure tha socket is in the good scope, try `console.log(socket)` and check it

Comment: All am getting is [object Object]

Comment: First, are you sure that the socket arrive to the server when you emit 'mute' from the client?

Comment: @BelowtheRader Ok so all aspects right now work, am pretty sure when I emit mute it isn't reaching the client, am unsure as to why, but every other aspect works accordingly.

Comment: mute is emitted by the client right? Have you tryed to listen to 'connection' event to see if your websocket reach the server at first

Comment: Yes it does reach the server, as suggested by @Anonymous0day I made sure it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From socket io doc: http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-the-express-framework

You could try to wrap you `'muting'` event listener in the `'connection'` event listener. Note that you will use the `socket` parameter from the `'connection'` event to listen to `'muting'`

server side:

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function (socket) {
  updateSip();
  socket.on('muting', function (data) {
     mute = data;
     console.log("client side:" + mute);
  });
});
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks very much for this! This should help me now when I need to pass in any data to the server in future.

Comment: Yes, because io.sockets is not the same object than socket. io.sockets is all sockets, socket is the specific socket...

Comment: This makes sense, am still fairly new to socket.io so this should be an immense help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

No you are not reaching your server !

```
 //Socket.io logic here
 server.listen(3009, function () {
     console.log('listening on *:3009');
 });
```

Your socket server seem to be listenning on port 3009, so you have to tell your client where is your server (the path -> ex : http://myoffice.localhost ) and the port to reach the server

try to update client side with :

```
 io.connect("wss://" + document.location.hostname + ':' + 3009);
```

Comment: What? Does this even mean, I am reaching it server side. Otherwise none of the current functionality I have would even work, I dont understand how this is the answer =/

Comment: I don't get how that's the answer, I already have the path...note am using express, but I tried your suggestion and the result is the exact same as it was before in every aspect so am unsure as to what that was suppose to do :( My webpage works fine with or without `("wss://" + document.location.hostname + ':' + 3009);` Just for some clarity my issue isn't connecting server side, my issue passing a value over to server side and storing it in a global var.

Comment: `var socket = io.connect();` this is your second line from your *Full client side code:* and there is no path

Comment: maybe update my example with your data : http instead of wss , and the path of your server instead of document.location.hostname

Comment: Yet the result is the exact same, I have applied the changes you suggested on the client side and nothing changed. It still worked like it did before when I applied it. I did update it accordingly